# How do I use Watson Assistant slots to save a value in a field of a context variable?

Tags: watson-assistant

I'd like to structure my Watson Assistant context variables into subgroups, but, e.g. saving a recognized value or entity in `context` as

```
"some": {
    "thing": "@an_entity"
}
```

but I'm not sure what syntax to use in the "Save It As" field. If I try to use the syntax describe in the documentation I get a warning

[image]

and if I open the JSON editor I get generated redundant entries like these

```
{
  "context": {
    "some": {
      "thing": "@an_entity"
    },
    "some.thing": "@an_entity"
  }
}
```

which then seem to proliferate (rather than change) every time I edit the "Save It As" field.

How do I use Watson Assistant slots to save a value in a field of a context variable?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the slots UI only accepts simple variables (not objects). You can work with objects within the JSON as you've seen, but there will be redundancy (as you've also seen).

It's probably simplest to just adopt a consistent naming convention for your variables, e.g. `$some_thing`, `$some_thing_else`, etc., to keep things organized.

Comment: But what is causing two rather than one context variable to  be created? How do I just get the first?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I suspect it's something in the way that context variables are being parsed on the back-end. I know that things you do in the dialog UI will directly affect the underlying dialog JSON, so I think something funky is happening there. I also get the sense that IBM doesn't really expect people to do what you're doing, which is why it's handled in a less than ideal way.

Comment: Yeah, basically it looks to me like a bug. I see (mostly) to get the result I want, but I also get a bunch of others, minimally every possible interpretation of what I've typed, but also a bunch of things I didn't type, or that are hanging around from a whole ago (long ago deleted). I think the connection between the JSON editor and the  "Save It As" field isn't quite working as it should.